# modification of TT template

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Is it possible to easily modify template (Template Toolkit) when it is loaded, before it is cached as Perl code? I want to run a regular expression on it.

Answer (score 5):

You can supply your own [Template::Provider](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Provider.html) that subclasses the standard one. From the fine manual:

> The Template::Provider is used to load, parse, compile and cache template documents. This
>   object may be sub-classed to provide more specific facilities for loading, or otherwise
>   providing access to templates.

So, it should be pretty easy but *easy*, of course, greatly depends on your skill.

Answer (score 4):

The Template::Provider suggestion above is probably the best way to do it. But there's also a simpler (if slightly hacky) approach. You can read the template into a scalar and run whatever transformations on it that you want before passing it to the template processor.

```
my $tt = Template->new;

open my $template_fh, '<', 'template.tt' or die $!;
my $template = do { local $/; <$template_fh> };

$template =~ s/some regex/some replacement/;

my $vars = { template => 'variables' };

$tt->process(\$template, $vars) or die $tt->error;
```

The secret is that the process() method takes various types of value as its first parameter. If you give if a scalar then that's assumed to be the name of a file that contains the template. But if it's a reference to a scalar, then it assumes that that scalar contains the actual template. See [the documentation](http://www.junauza.com/2010/12/top-50-programming-quotes-of-all-time.html) for more details.